# Optimizing row adding function in Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having issues with my Sheets script timing out because it's taking too long to run. The DateTime logging for this specific function of the script indicates that it is consistently taking > 2s to run.

Is there possibly a way to speed up the function?

```
function addTolog(product, shelf, amount, notes){

  let dt1 = new Date() //Record start time
  
  //log_ss and helpers_ss are global vars

  //Get last row value from a function result in a helper spreadsheet in the same workbook (Trying to save time on lookups)
  let lastRow = helpers_ss.getRange(1,2).getValue()

  log_ss.insertRowAfter(lastRow)

  //Insert values into new 2 dimensional array (single row)
  var values = 
  [
    [
    new Date(), product, shelf, amount, notes, Session.getActiveUser()
    ]
  ]
  
  log_ss.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,6).setValues(values) //Write the array into last row

  let dt2 = new Date(); //Record end time
  
  Logger.log("Log add time: " + (dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime())) //Log time difference
}
```

Comment: your script is making multiple api calls, not sure you can optimize your 2s run time

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk To add a question: Do these scripts run on the client side? It is triggered through an onEdit() and seems to run way way way faster on one computer vs another!

Comment: GAS runs on the server side. Whether it's triggered with `onEdit()` is not clear from the code you provided

Comment: You cannot speed up apps script in this case, but you can try using direct calls to sheets API, that's also will save you a couple ms

Comment: @Kos How exactly does one do such a thing?

Comment: @Lawrence for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838227/using-google-sheets-api-from-within-apps-script-for-same-sheet urlfetchapp + rest API

Comment: I can be wrong, but I've read somewhere that `getAcriveUser()` doesn't work well with `onEdit()` trigger. Probably this is the case. Try to exclude the `getActiveUser()` function from this part of the code.